# List that matches Android Phones to its Display Types

Tags: android, android-emulator, smartphone

If you develop for Android in Eclipse, you can choose from a list of display types (i.e. 5.4in FWVGA, 3.7in FWVGA, and so on...). I wonder if someone already made a list that matches each Android phone to its display type so I don't have to. Something like

- Nexus One -> 3.7in QVGA slider
- Samsung Galaxy S ->  ...

I alrady tried some Google queries but couldn't find anything. Someone got a link? Thanks

Comment: I don't know if there's an authoritative list. I know that some manufacturers have profiles for download on their websites. Samsung for example has one for their tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia to the rescue.  LOL.  It is not complete, but is a very good start.
[Wiki Link Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices)

Comment: I think the question is about what values to plug into the Emulator. The list kind of helps, but it's not exactly the same thing.